# Embedding YouTube iFrame on webpage causes A links in my UL LI nav to dissapear

Tags: css, google-chrome, iframe, youtube

I have a simple multi tier (3) UL > LI navigation which has some JS and CSS slapped on it. All works fine. Until I added a YouTube Video iFrame embed to the page, upon loading / reloading the page the links disappear, then next load they appear again. Mostly they are not visible, it all works fine on IE, FF, Edge, Safari and Opera, it's just Google Chrome (PC Win 10, All latest versions of the browsers).

I've tried setting CSS styles via jQuery after page load on all a elements, adding random ones, changing the html label to something then back again, even tried animating the colour of the text and the background with GSAP but nothing forces a reset of the css. I've watched the font (color RGBA) values tween in chrome code inspector live and nothing. If I inspect the page all the code is there perfect.

This is on a dev serer at the moment so can't give active preview.

Only cure is to either delete all css or the iframe.

**Anyone else got any ideas?**

ADDITIONAL
Tested with viemo iFrame and all functionality is restored, so youtube iframe is the issue.
iFrame code:

```
if ($article["youtube_header"] != "" && $article["youtube_header"] != null){
//echo('<iframe width="100%" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' . $article["youtube_header"] . '?wmode=transparent&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
}
```

HTML OF iFRAME

```
<iframe width="100%" height="400" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9SvpZ1OkvdE?wmode=transparent&rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

HTML RENDER OF NAV:

```
    <div id="aftc-nav">
    <div class="nav-top">Menu</div>
    <ul id='navulFsQTke4' data-tier='1'  class='nav-ul-tier-1'>
    <li><a href='/Dev/AFTC/AFTC_2016/www/category/cat-1-url' data-nid='166' data-pid='' data-cid='54' data-url='cat-1-url'  class='nav-a-tier-1' nav-first-a'>cat1</a></li>
    <li><a href='#' data-nid='167' data-pid=''  class='nav-a-tier-1 nav-parent'>cat2</a>
    <ul id='navulEmODx6F' data-tier='2'  class='nav-ul-tier-2'>
    <li><a href='/Dev/AFTC/AFTC_2016/www/article/art-2' data-nid='168' data-pid='167' data-aid='29' data-url='art-2' class='nav-a-tier-2'>art 2</a></li>
    <li><a href='/Dev/AFTC/AFTC_2016/www/article/art-1' data-nid='174' data-pid='167' data-aid='28' data-url='art-1' class='nav-a-tier-2'>art 1</a></li>
    </ul>
    </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="nav-btm"></div>
    </div>
```

CSS / LESS

```
  #aftc-nav {

  }

  #aftc-nav ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  #aftc-nav ul li {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  #aftc-nav .nav-top {
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    background: #333333;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    .roundTop;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
  }

  #aftc-nav .nav-btm {
    display: block;
    height: 30px;
    background: #333333;
    .roundBtm;
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
  }

  #aftc-nav .nav-first-a {

  }



  #aftc-nav a {
    display: block;
    font-family: "Roboto", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
  }

  #aftc-nav a:Hover {

  }

  #aftc-nav a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  #aftc-nav a:active {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }

  #aftc-nav a:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }




  #aftc-nav .nav-parent {
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }




  #aftc-nav .selected {
    background: #660000 !important;
  }
  #aftc-nav .selected:Hover {
    background: #990000 !important;
  }





  #aftc-nav .nav-a-tier-1 {
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 5px;
    background: #666666;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  #aftc-nav .nav-a-tier-1:hover {
    background: #990000;
  }

  #aftc-nav .nav-a-tier-2 {
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 15px;
    background: #444444;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  #aftc-nav .nav-a-tier-2:hover {
    background: #990000;
  }

  #aftc-nav .nav-a-tier-3 {
    padding: 3px 3px 3px 25px;
    background: #222222;
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
  #aftc-nav .nav-a-tier-3:hover {
    background: #990000;
  }
```

Ideas?

Thanks

D

Comment: Can you post your relative CSS and the relative code surrounding the iframe, including your UL and LIs

Comment: I've updated main question with code. The iFrame and DIV UL LI (nav) are in separate areas of the website. 2 column css layout Left fixed, fluid right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solutions:

1. Don't use a youtube iframe on your page.

or

2. Use google fonts via the JS code rather than the @import or html css link.

UPDATE: 19/04/2016
While adding elements to the page such as Flash and various other html, css and images this bug re-occurred just at less of a frequency on page re-load.

Solution was to not use google fonts, I took a download of the fonts and direct linked them via css.